# Need to match the annotation feature-UIMA RUTA

Tags: uima, ruta

I need to match the feature of an annotation and to also need to mark the second annotation of the matched feature. I've tried it but I'm facing two issues

**ISSUE 1:**

```
SEPERATEDA annotation values got reduced.I think its due to dictRemoveWS.
```

**ISSUE 2:**

```
It showing only the last match.(Due to some looping problem).
```

**Sample file 1:**

```
Arash Alipour
Rahul Bhargava
Lisette I.S. Wintgens
B. Rahul
Alipour A
Ali Aldabahi
M. Naziruddin Khan
Martin J. Swaans
Naziruddin Khan
```

Expected Output for file 1:

```
Rahul
Alipour
Naziruddin
Khan
```

**Sample file 2:**

```
M. Naziruddin Khan
Arash Alipour
Rahul Bhargava
Lisette I.S. Wintgens
Alipour A
Ali Aldabahi
M. Naziruddin Khan
```

Expected Output for file 2:

```
Alipour
Naziruddin
Khan
```

**My Script:**

```
PACKAGE uima.ruta.example;
DECLARE SINGLEINITIAL;

CW{REGEXP(".")->MARK(SINGLEINITIAL)};                   
DECLARE SeperateDA;
DECLARE DA;
"Arash Alipour"->DA;
"Lisette I.S. Wintgens"->DA;
"Alipour A"->DA;
"Rahul Bhargava"->DA;
"M. Naziruddin Khan"->DA;
"B. Rahul"->DA;
"Ali Aldabahi"->DA;
"A. S. Al Dwayyan"->DA;
"Lucas V.A. Boersma"->DA;
"Jippe C. Bal"->DA;
"Benno J.W.M. Rensing"->DA;
"Martin J. Swaans"->DA;

BLOCK(DocAuth) DA{}
{
CW{-PARTOF(SINGLEINITIAL)-> MARK(SeperateDA)};
}


DECLARE RepeatedDA(STRING auth);  
STRING MatchedAuth;
SeperateDA{->MARK(RepeatedDA),MATCHEDTEXT(MatchedAuth)}->{RepeatedDA{->RepeatedDA.auth=MatchedAuth};};
STRING auth;

FOREACH(RepAuth) RepeatedDA{}
 {  
    (da1:RepeatedDA {->UNMARK(RepeatedDA)}# da2:RepeatedDA){da1.auth != da2.auth};
 }
```

I also tried something like this

```
   da:RepeatedDA{->da.auth =  RepeatedDA.auth}; 
   FOREACH(RepAuth, true) RepeatedDA{}
          {
              # da:RepeatedDA{->auth =  da.auth, LOG("      auth-" +auth)};
              da:RepeatedDA {auth != da.auth-> UNMARK(da)};
          }
```

My goal is to remove the more over similar name from DA. For example from the above sample file both Rahul Bhargava and B. Rahul are in DA.But I need only Rahul Bhargava to be in DA.

Comment: Two intiial questions/comments: Why should 'Rahul' be annotated with `RepeatedDA ` in the first example? It is no `DA` thus no `SeperateDA` thus no `RepeatedDA`, thus the last rule doesn't matter at all. Do you omit the anchor variable in the FOREACH block by purpose? I'd assume that the first rule element should be `RepAuth`.

Comment: Sorry, Rahul is not in DA.I've edited the question now.There is no purpose to omit anchor variable.

Comment: Are you clear with the question now.

Comment: Let's see if it is clear to me. I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with your rule logic.

`da1:RepeatedDA # da2:RepeatedDA` da2 match always on the directly next RepeatedDA/SeperateDA since the value of the auth feature differs. Thus, the rule applies to often, almost every time.

Try this:

```
DECLARE SINGLEINITIAL;

CW{REGEXP(".")->MARK(SINGLEINITIAL)};                   
DECLARE SeperateDA (STRING auth);
DECLARE DA;
"Arash Alipour"->DA;
"Lisette I.S. Wintgens"->DA;
"Alipour A"->DA;
"Rahul Bhargava"->DA;
"M. Naziruddin Khan"->DA;
"B. Rahul"->DA;
"Ali Aldabahi"->DA;
"A. S. Al Dwayyan"->DA;
"Lucas V.A. Boersma"->DA;
"Jippe C. Bal"->DA;
"Benno J.W.M. Rensing"->DA;
"Martin J. Swaans"->DA;

BLOCK(DocAuth) DA{}
{
CW{-PARTOF(SINGLEINITIAL)-> CREATE(SeperateDA, "auth" = CW.ct)};
}

DECLARE RepeatedDA;
da1:SeperateDA{-> RepeatedDA} # da2:SeperateDA{da1.auth == da2.auth};
```

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*